# iPad App Development - Customize and Redistribute

Tags: ios, ipad

I need to make an iPad application that allows my customers to configure the app (load own database, pics) so it appears as their own. They would then be able to redistribute the app with their custom images, database, etc. The final end user would then grab the application and it would appear as an app created by the middleman (my customer). We can not give the middleman (my customer) the source code. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this something that your customer will upload to the store?

Comment: Preferably yes but if this isn't possible then we can do without.

Comment: I'm not certain of how well this would work but, in that case, I'd suggest exploring the idea of building all the functionality of your app into a static library (binary) and giving that to your customer.  (They would then need to add one source file (main.m) and their custom assets, build, and upload.)